# Write contents of excel into a text file

Tags: java, excel, list, text

I need to read the contents of an excel file and dump the same into a text file. I am able to read the contents from the file.
I created a `List excelData = new ArrayList();` which should hold the row data present in the excel sheet. But each column is of a different data type. How do I save the contents into the List ?

```
List excelData = new ArrayList();
    try {
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("H:\\Docs\\Medical Data Record\\MedicalRecord2015.xlsx"));
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        XSSFSheet ws = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator<Row> itr = ws.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            Row row = itr.next();
            Iterator<Cell> itrCell = row.cellIterator();
            while (itrCell.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = itrCell.next();
                switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        double val = cell.getNumericCellValue();
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        String txtval = cell.getStringCellValue();
                        break;
                }
            }
             }
```

Thanks

Comment: add your actual code.

Comment: `List<List<Object>> excelData = ... `  unfortunately there is no other way. If you know column structure, declare special object to represent a row.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't want to close the file where you do in the posted code

Comment: @RC.Ya. wasn't meant to be closed there. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you need not `List`, but `List<List<Object>>` here:

```
List<List<Object>> excelData = new ArrayList<>();

try {
   //...
   while (itr.hasNext()) {
       Row row = itr.next();
       List<Object> dataRow = new ArrayList<>();
       excelData.add(dataRow);
       Iterator<Cell> itrCell = row.cellIterator();
       while (itrCell.hasNext()) {
          Cell cell = itrCell.next();
          if (cell == null) {
               dataRow.add(null);
               continue;
          }
          switch (cell.getCellType()) {
          case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
              dataRow.add(cell.getNumericCellValue());
              break;
          case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
              dataRow.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
              break;
          case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
              dataRow.add(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
              break;
          case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
              dataRow.add("");
              break;
          default:
              dataRow.add(cell);
          }
      }
  }
```

Now, `excelData` contains `List` of rows represented as `List<Object>`, and can be easily saved to text file row by row. To achieve better consistency, you need also check another types of cell, like `Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN` or `null`.

Comment: Thanks. That gives me the desired output .